# I am shaggy below, Sometimes the beautiful. Who am I?

Tags: riddle

I am a wonderful help to women,
The hope of something to come. I harm
No citizen except my slayer.
Rooted I stand on a high bed.

I am shaggy below. Sometimes the beautiful
Peasant's daughter, an eager-armed,
Proud woman grabs my body,
Rushes my red skin, holds me hard,

Claims my head. The curly-haired
Woman who catches me fast will feel
Our meeting. Her eye will be wet.

Who am I?

Comment: Site policy is to cite your source for a puzzle.  This one came from the Exeter Book: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anglo-Saxon_riddles

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I guess you are a

> Red onion

Because:

> You shouldn't look at the lines, but you should read the sentences.
>
>  **I am a wonderful help to women, the hope of something to come**
>  Food? Food!
>
>  **I harm no citizen except my slayer**
>  Unless it's a poisoned onion it won't harm anyone except the one who's *slaying* it
>
>  **Rooted I stand on a high bed**
>  Here the word *bed* means *garden bed* or a *flowerbed* and onions have roots
>
>  **I am shaggy below**
>  Yes you are!
>
>  **Sometimes the beautiful Peasant's daughter, an eager-armed, Proud woman grabs my body, Rushes my red skin, holds me hard, Claims my head**
>  A peasant probably has a bed(or a few) of onions, so his daughter will grab one from there and peel it
>
>  **The curly-haired Woman who catches me fast will feel Our meeting**
>  I guess if you throw an onion really fast into somebody, he/she will certainly feel it :)
>
>  **Her eye will be wet**
>  When you cut the onion normally your eyes start crying. Or if you throw an onion reeeeeeally hard into somebody it might hurt enough for him/her to start crying :)

Comment: You got it. I found an other website with this exact same question.

Answer (score 5):

It is

> Red rose

I am a wonderful help to women,

> Help to their self esteem?

The hope of something to come.

> When a women receives a red rose, the hope is the one who gave it to her is her prince charming.

I harm No citizen except my slayer.

> The one who cutted the rose and removed all the thorns is the only harmed by it

Rooted I stand on a high bed.

> Rooted obviously, the high bed is the rest of the roses?

I am shaggy below.

> Full of leafs, which are removed

Sometimes the beautiful
Peasant's daughter, an eager-armed,
Proud woman grabs my body,
Rushes my red skin, holds me hard,
Claims my head.

> Peasant's daughters aren't princesses, they don't receive roses from princes so.. they have to take them by themselves.

The curly-haired
Woman who catches me fast will feel
Our meeting. Her eye will be wet.

> Impulsive woman who takes the rose before the thorns are removed. Don't know why curly...

Who am I?

Comment: I think "Claims my head. The curly-haired" might actually belong together - the head of the red rose is made of curly petals.

Comment: "The curly-haired
 Woman who catches me fast will feel
 Our meeting. Her eye will be wet." 
I thought this was referring to the wedding tradition of tossing a bouquet of flowers, since whoever catches it is, supposedly, the next person there to get married.

Answer (score 0):

Are you

> a brush?

I am a wonderful help to women,

> Not only women, though!

The hope of something to come. I harm

> You brush your hair before a date or whenever you want to be beautiful.

No citizen except my slayer.

> Normally it is not harmful, but if you hit it on the pointy ends...

Rooted I stand on a high bed.

> A round brush is often kept on the bathroom shelf, upright in a glas or so.

I am shaggy below. Sometimes the beautiful

> Brushes made of (horse)hair are quite shaggy.

Peasant's daughter, an eager-armed,

Proud woman grabs my body,

> She grabs the handle.

Rushes my red skin, holds me hard,

> She goes over the rubber part to clear out her hair of the brush.

Claims my head. The curly-haired

Woman who catches me fast will feel

Our meeting. Her eye will be wet.

> Brushing curly hair can be a pain. Ouch!

Who am I?